# Render into 2 offscreen textures at once in Metal fragment shader

Tags: ios, shader, metal, fragment-shader, metalkit

Metal fragment shader render into its render target by explicitly returning `float4` value. Does it mean that fragment shader can only render in one texture at once? I'd like to render into 2 textures at once, both at the same coordinates, but for now I have to resort to `texture2d.write` function for one of it, which doesn't seem too natural for me. Is there a way to make both textures to be render targets at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a `struct` from the fragment shader instead, where each variable has the type you want to output (like `float4`) and an attribute like `[[color(i)]]` where `i` is the index of the color attachment from `MTLRenderPassDescriptpr`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Is something like that also possible the other way around, i.e. somehow map two read-only texture bindings to be a struct argument into the shader?

Comment: That's basically an argument buffer. You could create a struct that looks like two `MTLResourceID`s on the GPU and two `texture2d<...>` or whatever on GPU, and then fill it out on CPU. I usually use a macro like this: `
#ifdef __METAL_VERSION__
using namespace metal;
#define TEXTURE(textureType, pixelType, access) ::metal::texture##textureType<pixelType, (access)>
#else
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Metal/MTLTypes.h>
#define TEXTURE(textureType, pixelType, access) MTLResourceID
#endif`

Comment: Wow, the formatting in the comments sucks, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! Haven't worked with argument buffers yet. Probably an overkill for my case since I definitely don't have any issues with CPU overhead, but it's good to know!